# Autocomplete not working in Gridview HeaderTemplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, aspxgridview

**Adding textbox inside Gridview control :**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Names" SortExpression="Names">
<HeaderTemplate>
Enter Stock Name :<asp:textbox runat="server" id="txtAutoComplete" cssclass="autosuggest" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:textbox>
</HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**After Adding jquery as well in  please see below.**

```
function SearchText() {
$(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "Index1.aspx/getCustomerNames",
```

txtAutoComplete textbox working fine when outside grid but it is not working When I place inside HeaderTemplate

suggestions please

Comment: txtAutoComplete textbox working outside gridview but I place same contrl inside gridview HeaderTemplate not working

Comment: Why you have created function? You can just put $(".autosuggest").autocomplete

Comment: @KevinShah Thanks for your reply. I tried but it is not working.Textbox inside HeaderTemplate  of gridview.

Comment: @KevinShah I am getting "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference " in browser console

Comment: It is working when I change ASP control to normal input textbox type . From <asp:textbox runat="server" id="Textbox6" cssclass="autosuggest"></asp:textbox> to <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" class="autosuggest" />.